# Securing WCF 4.5 service using Azure ACS 2.0

Tags: wcf, azure, acs, ws-federation, ws-trust

How can I secure my WCF 4.5 service using Azure ACS 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic tutorial: [WCF (SOAP) Service With Federated Authentication](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4027.wcf-soap-service-with-federated-authentication.aspx)
Then you can look at samples by Dominick Baier and Brock Allen here: [Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/tree/master/Samples).

Also you can try to use Visual Studio tool for adding STS reference and point it to Azure ACS.
AFAIK endpoint Uri is something like this for client certificate authentication:

```
https://myacsnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wstrust/13/certificate
```

More  samples are located here: [Windows Azure AD Access Control (ACS) Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385/sourcecode?fileId=71587&pathId=477793108)

If you have questions, consider asking them as separate and more specific topics.